# Scan current URL and compare with buffer in tosca

Tags: tosca

After logging into website, it might go to proofing page  and then to the landing page or directly to the landing page, which uncontrolled and unpredictable.  So I scanned the Proofing page and compared the URL in my testcase, but its failing as its directly going to landing page. And if I do viceversa it will work when landing page comes first but fails when proofing page comes inbetween. Is there any way I could handle this scenario.

thanks
Anjana.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Firefox browser, go to setting about:config and change:
accessibility.blockautorefresh=true

Then the forwarding will not take affect.
**Description:** *"Instead of refreshing a page automatically when  is present (or Refresh HTTP headers), display a browser message indicating the refresh and allow the user to follow it manually."*

[accessibility.blockautorefresh=true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiNr4.png)

Willi